# How can I move an SVG mask to show a shape that is initially hidden?

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create an animation like the one in this gif :

[image: example gif]

Here is my HTML/SVG/CSS :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>svg animation logo</title>
    <style>
      path,
      line,
      circle {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #164a07;
        stroke-width: 4;
      }

      svg {
        background: #9bc345;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="180" height="180" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="squars">
      <path id="sq3" d="m 55.693069,108.71287 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.38613 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
      <path id="sq2" d="m 54.56835,75.965348 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.386127 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
      <path id="sq1" d="m 55.459439,43.886141 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.386127 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ticks">
      <path id="tick1" d="m 60.136501,49.945523 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.930694 12.252476,-16.707921 6.237623,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772"/>
      <path id="tick2" d="m 60.816832,82.871287 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.930694 12.252476,-16.707921 6.237623,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772"/>
      <path id="tick3" d="m 60.359273,115.2178 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.93069 12.252476,-16.70792 6.237623,0.22277 -0.222773,0.22277 -0.222773,0.22277"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I can hide the checkmarks with a mask :

```html
<defs>
    <mask id="mmm">
        <rect width="180" height="50" x="0" y="92" fill="black" />
        <rect width="180" height="98" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
    </mask>
</defs>
```

But I can't figure out how to have them animate in. I think that I need to use `<animateTransform attributeName="transform"` but I don't really understand how to do it. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would make more sense to animate the [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray). With that, you can control the part of the path that should be visible. The `pathLength` attribute determines the full length of the path and then the first value in the `stroke-dasharray` attribute controls the length of the stroke.

I "chained" together all the animation, so that they begin one after the other.

```css
path,
line,
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #164a07;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

svg {
  background: #9bc345;
}
```

```html
<svg width="180" height="180" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="squars">
    <path id="sq3" d="m 55.693069,108.71287 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.38613 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
    <path id="sq2" d="m 54.56835,75.965348 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.386127 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
    <path id="sq1" d="m 55.459439,43.886141 20.940594,0.44555 0.891089,21.386127 -21.831683,-0.44554 z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="ticks">
    <path id="tick1" d="m 60.136501,49.945523 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.930694 12.252476,-16.707921 6.237623,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772" pathLength="10" stroke-dasharray="0 10">
      <animate id="ani1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="1s" values="0 10;10 10" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
    <path id="tick2" d="m 60.816832,82.871287 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.930694 12.252476,-16.707921 6.237623,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772 -0.222773,0.222772" pathLength="10" stroke-dasharray="0 10">
      <animate id="ani2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="ani1.end" values="0 10;10 10" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
    <path id="tick3" d="m 60.359273,115.2178 6.237623,7.79703 c 0,0 6.014852,-16.93069 12.252476,-16.70792 6.237623,0.22277 -0.222773,0.22277 -0.222773,0.22277" pathLength="10" stroke-dasharray="0 10">
    <animate id="ani3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="ani2.end" values="0 10;10 10" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And you can basically do the same kind of animation on the text/lines that need to be to the right.

Comment: Thanks, I had some problems with drawing lines, but now I understand what needs to be done. Although, to be honest, I did not understand how to make the animation continue indefinitely, since repeatcount="indefinite" will not work, perhaps because the animations are "linked". But anyway, thanks, it solved my problem.